# Need help in Permission for Form Library in sharepiont 2010

Tags: permissions

I have a requirement that normal user can submit the the document in the Form Library(Sharepoint 2010) but he 
can not delete the document from library.To achieve this I have created using out of the box feature the below steps:
1)Site Settings
2)Site permision
3)Permission Level here i have created custom permission level with the following permission:

Add Items, Edit Items, View Items, View Pages, Open then clicked on Submit Button.
Note:In the above permision i have not selected the Delete option.
After Creating custom permission level i went to the Form Library-->Permission For this Library->
->Then I have modified the existing permision for the particular group which was Contribute now i assigend my custom
permission level which i created.

Now the problem is after changing this permisison with custom permision level user can not see the 
Form Library itself..could somebody pls help me whats wrong with my steps or approach.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely did not include something that requires the user to be able to view something.  To get the best results when creating a custom permission, it is my experience it's best to copy an existing permission level (Contribute in this case) them modify the copied permission and save as your custom.

In that scenario, you'd copy the Contribute permission, then deselect the Delete options and save it.  THen apply that permission level to the users on that library.

Your process is correct, but there's some issue with the permission level you created most likely.